# angularjs is not working in my own function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am using phonegap plus angularjs. My problem is calling function in object function. I show my code. i am not understand how to fix this issue. i want to calling **helloworld** function in object function.

```
<div class="newsFeeds-box" ng-app="pkdNewsFeeds" ng-controller="pkNewsFeedsController">
    <article class="container-news-box" ng-repeat="x in newsFeeds">
        <p class="newsFeeds-title ">{{ x.id }}</p>
    </article>
</div>


<script>
 // this function is getting data array 
 storage.getNewsFeeds(storage.db,function(resultSet) {
    helloworld.call(this,resultSet);  // this function is not working. I will passing my resultSet with this function
},3);


function helloworld(resultSet) {

//this is dummy data
    var newsFeedsData = [{id:"rdsf111111",longDesp:"djfsdf dsfsdf sdfsf"},{id:"rdsf22222",longDesp:"djfsdfasdasdasdasd dsfdsf vsdvsd"}];

    var pkdNewsFeedsrun = angular.module(' pkdNewsFeeds ', []);

    pkdNewsFeedsrun.controller('pkNewsFeedsController', function($scope) {

        $scope.newsFeeds = newsFeedsData;

    });
    }
   <script>
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: helloworld function from storage.getNewsFeeds

Answer (score 0):

Module name is having spaces.
Can you replace `var pkdNewsFeedsrun = angular.module(' pkdNewsFeeds ', []);`
 with `var pkdNewsFeedsrun = angular.module('pkdNewsFeeds', []);`
and test

Comment: i check my code pkdNewsFeedsrun.controller is not working. i am using phonegap + angularjs

Answer (score -1):

In your controller you need to add `['$scope', function($scope){...}]`. Also I don't think you can create an angularjs module inside a function so you should create the module and controller outside of the function and look at the documentation for [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) or use pure javascript to render the newsFeedData maybe something like:

```
var a = document.getElementByClassName('newsFeeds-box')[0]
for (var i in resultSet){
    var b = document.createElement('article')
    var c = document.createElement('p')
    c.setAttribute('class', 'newsFeeds-title')
    c.innerText = resultSet.id
    a.appendChild(b);
    b.appendChild(c);
}
```

This would have to be optimized, but it should work.